# Handle multiple version at the same time?

Tags: python, opencv

I am currently developing an application based on Opencv ([more info here](http://jlengrand.github.com/FaceMovie/)).
In order to ensure that everything is working fine, I would like to try the same code with multiple versions of OpenCV (2.3, 2.4).

This is mainly aiming for Linux development, but I wouldn't mind finding a solution for Windows also.

As a bonus, I'd really be glad If I could also switch between version from packages, and other compiled from sources.

The solution I am currently thinking about is to download and compile several versions (without the make install) and then use the chosen release folder manually for imports. 
This doesn't solve the package intstall issue, and may not be really usable in the long run

What yould be the best way to achieve such an objective ?

Comment: Sorry but I can not see the reason why you would want your code to work with multiple opencv versions. The proper opencv version will ship with your code as a library, it's not like you are going to ship your code to systems that might have different versions of the library. I am not sure about the python side but a lot has changed in version 2.4, some function parameters would be an example, so an app programmed for 2.3 will be slightly different than for 2.4.

Comment: And here is the very reason why I want to be able to see what is and is not working using different versions. the ubuntu packages now offer a 2.3 precompiled version through Synaptic, but my latest Fedora users would be likely to dl the last version (2.4)> I want to test both versions, without having to install two Linux systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) seems to be the good solution for this :

> virtualenv is a tool to create isolated Python environments.
>
> ...
>
> Imagine you have an application that needs version 1 of LibFoo, but
> another application requires version 2. How can you use both these
> applications?

Comment: Thx Cédriv. I already know about virtualenv, but isn't this aiming at package that can be installed using pip ?

Comment: Couldn't you have several virtualenv environments with your opencv libs and a script kick off your automated tests against each environment. That way you can test against multiple opencv versions.

Comment: @jlengrand : you can use virtualenv for manually installed modules (juste use `/path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/python setup.py install`)

Comment: Hum, seems interesting indeed. I'll try that tonight and let you know :). Thx